# Fetching html with cheerio

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I'm using `cheerio`, How Can I Get `content`?

My Code is okey with This:

```
request('https://example.com', function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
      console.log(html);
  }
});
```

**I need to get `사이드` from `content`:**

```
<meta property="og:description" content=" I'm Jack">
<meta property="og:title" content="사이드">  // How to Get `사이드` and print in console.log?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
request('https://example.com', function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);
      console.log($("meta[property='og:title']").attr("content"));    
  }
});
```

Side node ( related to a previous error in the answer ) :

You should be aware when using cheerio that it only emulates some aspect of the jQuery api and does not recreate a whole DOM. Which means that contrary to a previous version of this answer you **cannot** do :

`$("meta").get(1).getAttribute("origin");`  which will result in a TypeError for trying to call on `undefined`. Cheerio builds a representation of the DOM upon which a subset of the jQuery api is implemented. The `get` api exists but will return this representation and not the standard DOM one, and there are no `getAttribute`method attached to the cheerio representation. If you want a complete DOM representation and jQuery you need to use something like **jsdom**.

Comment: Solved with First one and When I used Secent one I Got: `console.log($("meta").get(1).attr("content"));` ,  `TypeError: $(...).get(...).attr is not a function`

Comment: Hello, I made a mistake that I fixed, using *get* actually returns the underlying DOM element, so you need to use *getAttribute* and not *attr* for it to work. I added a comment because I did not test it with cheerio but it's valid in the browser. Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: Dear @adz5A my problem Solved with first one but in secend one I got this for your new update: `TypeError: $(...).get(...).getAttribute is not a function`

Comment: I'll try when I get home. this is the purpose of my comment in that cheerio does not build a dom. however when on the browser you can access underlying dom objects. I will edit later with more details regarding the cheerio imperative of the jquery api

Comment: I found the solution, I used .eq(1) instead of .get(1)

Answer (score 0):

**First way:** `console.log($("meta[property='og:title']").attr("content"));` Solved By @adz5A

**Secend way:** `console.log($("meta").eq(1).attr("content"));`

`.get()` returns a DOM object.
Cheerio is not a browser, so the DOM api is not available.